# Which galaxy does the name "Guardians of the Galaxy" refer to?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(film)):

> *Guardians of the Galaxy* (retroactively referred to as *Guardians of the
>   Galaxy Vol. 1*) is a 2014 American superhero film based on the
>   Marvel Comics superhero team of the same name, produced by Marvel
>   Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is
>   the tenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). Part 2 was released in 2017.

[image: DVD cover showing the main characters]

So my question is, which galaxy does the film's name "Guardians of the Galaxy" refer to?

Comment: I've rewritten the question so it's clearer and easier to read, but I'm still not sure why you believe that "Guardians of **the Galaxy**" could refer to *multiple* galaxies.

Comment: You might be confusing the "vol. 1", "vol. 2" which refers to the movies, not more than one galaxies.

Comment: Iron Man is not (predominantly) made of iron. Hawkeye only has human eyes. Why are you assuming that a hero's name is pedantically accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title is just generic and obvioulsy ties directly to the comic.

It doesn't *have* to refer to a specific galaxy but it scans slightly better than "Guardians of the Galaxies".

For an official word...

In fact *GotG* is set in the **Andromeda** galaxy as indicated by James Gunn in [**this Q&A**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153003/which-galaxy-was-featured-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy) over on our sister site Science Fiction & Fantasy

> > Here's [Gunn responding](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153003/which-galaxy-was-featured-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy) to the question asked in a April 2016 tweet:
> >
> > **@CryHavoc01**: @JamesGunn @MAldinnur so The Galaxy they're Guarding isn't the Milky Way? Is it a specific Galaxy?
> >
> > **@JamesGunn**: Andromeda.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a trick question.  See, the first movie took place partially on [Xandar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xandar), which is said (in the comics) to be in the Andromeda galaxy.  The second movie takes place mostly in the [Black Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_the_Living_Planet#1960s), as that is where Ego exists (again, according to the comics).  Lastly, they help The Avengers battle Thanos in Infinity War, which takes place on Earth in the Milky Way Galaxy.

So, the Guardians of the Galaxy actually help protect whichever galaxy they happen to be in at that time.

Answer (score -1):

As you know you can't be in two places at once. So can't Guardians. They can be only in one galaxy. And if that one particular galaxy would be destroyed they try to save it.

As explained in this particular scene by these two particular people Before they were guardians.

[image: Whole title explanation]

Answer (score -2):

It is referring to multiple guardians since that is the plural word not multiple galaxies.

Think of it like this Guardians(multiple) of the Galaxy(single).

If you are asking which galaxy the answer would be ours since star lord is a human and was kidnapped from earth at the start of the movie.